# Spark code to apply SUM agg function

Tags: apache-spark

My input file is  below

```
surender,2015-JAN,100
raja,2015-JAN,20
kumar,2015-FEB,2
ajay,2015-FEB,23
```

I need to create a output as " find the total amount spent on each month "

Expected output

```
2015-JAN,120
2015-FEB,25
```

I tried the below code in spark shell

```
scala> val fileRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/records.txt")

scala> val mapRDD  = fileRDD.map(x => (x.split(",")(1),x.split(",")(2)))

scala> val reduceRDD = mapRDD.reduceByKey((a,b) => (a+b))

scala> reduceRDD.collect
```

I am getting output,but it is not correct . Concat operation is applied on amount .

```
 res21: Array[(String, String)] = Array((2015-JAN,10020), (2015-FEB,223))
```

How do I typecast it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second portion of your map add .toInt:

```
val mapRDD  = fileRDD.map(x => (x.split(",")(1),x.split(",")(2).toInt))
```

It still sees it as a String if you do not do this, now it will add integers.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is :

```
val fileRDD = sc.textFile("test.txt")
val mapRDD  = fileRDD.map(x => (x.split(",")(1),x.split(",")(2).toInt))
val reduceRDD = mapRDD.reduceByKey(_ + _)
reduceRDD.collect.foreach(println)
```